# How to update one column in datagridview using stored procedure and Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to update one column (specifically the `Status` column to "2") based on what I click on the datagridview row.

I created a stored procedure first:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CCSDD_StatusUpdate] 
    @status int,
    @id int
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    UPDATE CCSDD_StoreDirectDelivery1 
    SET Status = 2 
    WHERE ID = @id
END
```

Then I called it inside a button event

```
private void btnCommit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    using (DataClasses2DataContext db = new DataClasses2DataContext())
    {
        var row = dgvDisplay.CurrentRow.Index;
        db.CCSDD_StatusUpdate(2, row);
        dgvDisplay.Refresh();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Your status has been updated!");
}
```

There is no error when I click the "Commit" button, but it is not updating the status column. Can anyone help me?

Comment: do you see the Message box? What is the status value you are updating to?

Comment: Your `db` (`DbContext`) **has no idea** that your `PROCEDURE` updated an entity that's already been loaded in-memory. You will need to use `Reload` to reload that entity.

Comment: `CurrentRow.Index;` <-- Uhhhh, the row-index *is a completely separate thing* compared to your CCSDD_StoreDirectDelivery1.ID` column. You need to pass the **actual** `ID` value in that row, not its `Index`.

Comment: @Chetan Yes i am seeing the message box, the original value of Status is 1.

Comment: @Dai how do I do that? Sorry I am a complete newbie in c#

Comment: @beans Why are you using a `PROCEDURE` at all, anyway? EF can handle that `UPDATE` for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the correct code myself, I just changed the `Status =2` in sql to `Status = @status` then updated the code in the button

```cs
private void btnCommit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (DataClasses2DataContext db = new DataClasses2DataContext())
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to commit it?","Yes",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            int i = dgvDisplay.CurrentRow.Index;
            ID = dgvDisplay[7, i].Value.ToString();
                  
            db.CCSDD_StatusUpdate(2, ID);
            MessageBox.Show("Your Status has been updated!");
        }               
    }         
}
```